# How to set customize currency in java?

Tags: java, format, set, currency

I tried to make manual currency. Here is my code

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setCurrencySymbol("$");
dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
System.out.println(df.format(3333454));
```

Program output is

> 3.333.454

Why the currency symbol I set didn't appear?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
NumberFormat df = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setCurrencySymbol("$");
dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
dfs.setMonetaryDecimalSeparator('.');
((DecimalFormat) df).setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
System.out.println(df.format(3333454));
```

Comment: thanks dude, it works. But how to remove 2 decimal digit behind?

Comment: Add `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);`

Answer (score 4):

Because you use the [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) with the standard pattern. You need to provide your custom pattern with the `\u00A4` currency symbol.

Or you use [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

You've told the DecimalFormat which currency symbol to use when it must format a currency. But you haven't told it to format a currency. The default pattern used by the no-arg constructor isn't meant to format currencies. Use a dedicated pattern for that.

[The javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) tells you everything you need to know.