# How to parse "1,23$" in java using NumberFormat class and obtain 123 as number

Tags: java, number-formatting

I tried the following code samples, but did not work,

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse("1,23$")
```

throws below exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "1,23$"
```

Comment: You could try manually going through the string and parsing.

Comment: You can use REGEX to remove `$` `,` or `.` etc and then parse it

Comment: I need a consistent api especially using NumberFormat that could parse "$1,23" and "1,23$" both, I do not wish to parse the string manually

Comment: @Muhammad, yes, I know these basic stuffs but I am only intended to do it through NumberFormat classes

Comment: If you are only interested in the numbers, why do you need to use numberformat?

Comment: @cricket_007 because these value are amount in the form of plain string, plz notice I am using "Locale" because "1,23$" or "$1,23" are representing amounts in specific currency

Comment: But if you only want 123, why does the format matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check both with one number format. You would need to try one if the other fails:

```java
DecimalFormat format1 = 
    (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
format1.applyPattern("##,#0¤");

DecimalFormat format2 = 
    (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
format2.applyPattern("¤##,#0");

System.out.println(format1.parse("1,23$"));
System.out.println(format2.parse("$1,23"));
```

This uses the currency pattern placeholder `¤`.

Comment: this is one of the closest answer to my requirement, I can manage to get the pattern at runtime, thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2):

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setCurrencySymbol("$");
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);       
    final Number parse = df.parse("1,23$");
    System.out.println(parse);
```

Comment: The input has a comma, not a decimal

Comment: You were right, I guess this works. I adapted this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536899/how-to-set-customize-currency-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want this

```
public int getValue(String s) {
    return Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", ""));
}
```

Comment: sure, this will work in fact I've tried this but is there any way to do this using NumberFormat or any third party library that supports parsing for both "1,23$" and "$1,23"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements. An Integer is a Number subclass, why does it matter how you get it?

Comment: ok, if this is all there is then what is point of adding NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance afterall in the jdk,? there is some purpose of using this api, hence I'd like to use this CurrencyInstance to parse any given amount such as "1,23€", "€2,34", "$3,2", "5.6$" using a single common api, that's why I am looking for using either NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(..) something similar to this, : )

Comment: It's used when you actually need to parse a currency, not just get all numeric values within a string. There's more than one solution to simple problems

Answer (score 0):

Reformat your string.

```java
String s = "1,23$";
s = '$' + s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse(s));
```

Comment: Why parse using currency at all? You've removed the dollar and comma, so just parse as int

Answer (score 0):

```
Number number = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse("$1,23");

        System.out.println("Number is "+ number ) ;
```

And Output is

```
Number is 123
```

if you pass value `1,23$`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "1,23$"
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:385)
    at com.example.polls.PollsApplicationTests.main(PollsApplicationTests.java:18)
```

Comment: my input is: "1,23$" and however the parse function should work for both "$1,23" and "1,23$"

Comment: @Manoranjan nay be you have to once more about parse function

Comment: I've amount data with currency symbol present within the data like: "1,23€", "€2,34", "$3,2", "5.6$" where the currency symbol can only be either at the end or at the start, and I need to parse all these currency data using NumberFormat using the same code, if not NumberFormat, a 3rd party library will work fine to me

Comment: then remove all currency symbol and parse plain text

Comment: yes I already tried removing all currency symbol and it worked in fact, but my doubt is: but then what is the point of having NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(..) in the JDK

Comment: is you talking about NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance then you have to provide a proper format that it accept you can't make your format and parse in it